# Hibernate Inheritance, parent classes should be child or parent based on decider

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Trying to achieve inheritance in Hibernate.

Following is schema

[image]

Here is What, Classes are,

```
//Grand Parent Class
@Entity
@Table(name="grand_parent")
public class GrandParent{//consider @id}

//Parent Class
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent") 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "decider", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Parent{//consider @id}

//ChildX class
@Entity
@Table(name = "childX")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
@DiscriminatorValue("X")
public class ChildX() extends Parent{//consider value}

//ChildY class
@Entity
@Table(name = "childY")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
@DiscriminatorValue("Y")
public class ChildY extends Parent(//consider value){}

//ChildZ class
@Entity
@Table(name = "childZ")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
@DiscriminatorValue("Z")
public class ChildZ() extends Parent{//consider value}
```

**Use Case:**

- If decider is 'K', and 4 records need to be saved then 4 parent records should be added
- If decider is 'X/Y/Z', and 4 records need to be saved then, 1 parent record and 4 ChildX/ChildY/ChildZ records should be added.

[image]

However, parent table should be treated as single child when decider is 'K' and it must be acted as parent when decider is 'X/Y/Z'

But with above class diagram, Whenever decider is 'X/Y/Z', 4 records saved in ChildX/ChildY/ChildZ and no record in parent table.

Also how to retrieve above records.

**EDITS**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="grand_parent")
public class GrandParent{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentRecord", 
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE)
private List<parent> parentList;
}

//Parent Class
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent") 
public class Parent{
 @ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_gp_id")
private GrandParent parentRecord;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "childrecord", 
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE)
private List<Child> childList;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "decider", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Child(){
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_parent_id")
private parent childrecord;
}

//ChildX class
@Entity
@Table(name = "childX")
@DiscriminatorValue("X")
public class ChildX() extends Parent{//consider value}
......
```

To add..

```
GrandParent gp = new GrandParent();
Parent p = new Parent();
ChildX ch = new ChildX();
ch.setChildrecord(p);
p.setChildList(//Array added ch);
p.setParentRecord(gp);
gp.setParentList(//Array added p);
persist(gp);
```

Now I am getting an error:

> Application error : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'Child' doesn't exist

Comment: Should the children not extend the Parent? And if ```Parent``` can't exist on it's own you should make it abstract.

Comment: Updated my quest. Yes child extends parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use (Joined) inheritance you will always insert a row in both the Parent and Child table when you persist a child. This means that every Parent has at most one child. 
In you table diagram, you have multiple children with the same parent, this is not inheritance, this is a OneToMany Entity relationship, which is confirmed by your ER diagram.

My guess is that you are looking for something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Collection<Child> children; 
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "decider", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Child {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
    // other common fields
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("X")
public class ChildX extends Child {
    // specific fields for child x
} 

// more children types
```

A parent can have many children, and these children can be of different types. The child base class has the foreign key column referencing the parent, in my experience inheritance base classes often end up being abstract.

**EDIT:** Here is an example of code that stores a Parent and a specific child.

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
try {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Parent p = new Parent();
    ChildX childX = new ChildX();
    childX.setParent(p);
    em.persist(p);
    em.persist(childX);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

Comment: I tries it.. error is Table Child doesn't exist. As there is no Table 'Child'

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Entities, so how do you created the tables? Also you need to specify when you get the error, and if it is when you persist, how does the code look. I will edit my answer to include the JPA to save a Parent and a specific Child.

Comment: The code looks fine, as long as you persist all entities either directly or through cascade. If there is no table child, then check you create statement and database layout. If your tables are created by hibernate automatically (only recommended for development) then perhaps you need to drop the database and start with a clean one.

Comment: AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java -> function persist(entity) used to persist. Still no clue..

Comment: From your post, comments and edits, I assume that you are fairly new to JPA. Have you tried staring with a simpler example to learn the basic and build the solution one Entity at the time? I have tested the code locally and it works, so unless you can create the project on GitHub, so I can see all the code and configuration, I can't help you anymore.